# Delaying the Roll out of Offer Letter

Tags: job-offer

I'm an experienced professional and I applied for an opening through Job Board. My profile got shortlisted and I gave 1 Aptitude written test, 1 telephonic interview (technical) , 2 face to face technical interviews. Post the 2nd interview, the I was told that i'm selected and they'll be rolling out the offer soon. However it's been 2 weeks and I've still not heard anything from the HR. I called them 3-4 times but they kept on delaying giving some excuse. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest trying somewhere else. There will always be companies who keep on delaying accepting or refusing you. Don't put all your eggs in one basket.